# Stop marzipan drying out during storage (eg. on Battenberg)

Tags: cake, storage

I bought a Battenberg cake and ate it over the course of a couple of weeks.  To try and stop the marzipan wrapping drying out I stored it in clingfilm; however, after a week, the marzipan had still somewhat dried out and become more brittle.  Am I missing a trick?  Is there a better way to store it that will help keep it in its original state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chill it in the fridge for an hour or two (aids slicing) before you open it, then slice it all immediately.

Wrap each slice separately & freeze.

I'm not sure I'd want to eat 2-week-old sponge cake whether it was wrapped in marzipan or not, kept anywhere except a freezer. This type of product is only shelf-stable until it's opened, after that its life-span is short.